# Use of Stdin and Stdout

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, stdout, stdin

I have to use a sample code in which I have to provide the **file source name** and the **destination file name**. Then these name will be send to an another function as shown in the code below

```
    int def(FILE *source, FILE *dest, int level)
    {
        ----
        -----

        return Z_OK;
    }



    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        int ret;

        /* avoid end-of-line conversions */
        SET_BINARY_MODE(stdin);
        SET_BINARY_MODE(stdout);

        // do compression if no arguments 
        if (argc == 1) 
        {
            ret = def(stdin, stdout, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
            if (ret != Z_OK)
            {
                zerr(ret);
                return ret;
            }
              // otherwise, report usage 
            else 
            {
                fputs("zpipe usage: zpipe [-d] < source > dest\n", stderr);
                return 1;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

I do not undertsnad, how ***stdin*** and ***stdout*** are passing the input and output file names. Furthermore, I am not able to provide the correct sequence of source and destination file names as the command arguments. Most of the time I get `zpipe usage: zpipe [-d] < source > dest`.

**UPDATE:** The complete sample code is present at [**this link**](http://www.zlib.net/zpipe.c)

Answer (score 0):

When using `stdin` and `stdout`, file names are not passed. These files are already open when `main` is called, and the program can just read/write them. The parent process (usually the shell) then takes care of feeding the data to `stdin` and doing something with data from `stdout` of the program.

In your example usage `zpipe < sourcefile > destinationfile`, the shell opens *sourcefile* for reading, and gives the open file to *zpipe*, and also creates *destinationfile* for writing, and writes to it whatever the program outputs to its `stdout`. The *zpipe* program does not get name of either file, it just gets the open file handles.

Also, the `< sourcefile` and `> destinationfile` are not arguments to *zpipe*. Shell parses and handles them as described above, *zpipe* does not get them as arguments.

Comment: thanks, but which files are open? How do I tell it, which file i want to pass and where do I want to get output?

Comment: `>` is used to redirect `stdout`, ie. the stdout output of the program goes to whatever file you put after it. And `<` is used to redirect `stdin`, whatever the program reads comes from the file after it. (A bit extra: There's also the pipe `|`, which is used between two processes, and it acts like `>` for the program on left side, and as `<` for program on the right side.). From the program, you can't (easily) tell where the output goes or where the input comes in, you just read/write.

Comment: Is there any way that I can provide my own source file and store the results into a destinationo file? I mean, what modification should I make so that it takes my source file ?

Comment: if I use  `FILE *pSRC = fopen("srcFile.pdf")` and `FILE *pDST = fopen("dstFile.pdf")` `ret = def(pSRC , pDST , Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION)`....it doesn't work

Comment: Does giving shell command `zpipe < srcFile.pdf > dstFile.pdf` work? Also "it does not work" is not very useful problem description...

Comment: I wrote `zpipe < srcFile.pdf > dstFile.pdf` as command argument in VS2010 and I got the error `Ùnable to start program....Input or output cannot be redirected because the specified file is invalid`. Both the files `srcFile.pdf` and `dstFile.pdf` are present in the folder containing `.exe` file

Comment: @user2756695 if `dstFile.pdf` exists, then it may fail because of that, when the shell (CMD.EXE?) refuses to "clobber" the output file. This is generally configurable, but I don't remember the default for CMD.EXE or how to change it.

Comment: I deleted the `dstFile.pdf` but I still get the same error